# Flutter-Firestore "The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>"

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, flutter-web

I try to review my data inside firebase firestore. But this error is come inside my firestore_service.dart file.Can you help me solve this error.

"**The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>**"

This is my firestore_service.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:esrimarket/note.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class FirestoreService {
  static final FirestoreService _firestoreService =
      FirestoreService._internal();
  Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;

  FirestoreService._internal();

  factory FirestoreService() {
    return _firestoreService;
  }

  getNotes(){
    return _db
    .collection('notes')
    .snapshots()
    .map((snapshot)=>snapshot.documents.map((doc)=>Note.fromMap(doc.data, doc.documentID)));
  }
}
```

This is my note.dart file

```
class Note{
  final String name;
  final String price;
  final String quantity;
  final String id;

  Note({this.name, this.price, this.quantity, this.id});

  Note.fromMap(Map<String,dynamic> data, String id):
    name=data["name"],
    price=data["price"],
    quantity=data["quantity"],
    id=id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing brackets after the member `data` because it's a function:

```
Note.fromMap(doc.data(), doc.documentID)

                     ^^
```